# Next Previous button for load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have load function which fetches content from html files here is the code.

```
$('#content').load("pages/sample.html", function(){
    //Load Content Using Menu Links
    $('.main-menu a').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load('pages/' + page + '.html');
        return false;

    });
});
```

1. Now I want to create next previous buttons for each load. Any idea?

Comment: do you have a list of all the html filenames?

Comment: yes i have list of filenames, i just want to fetch the href of prev and next page load and add it to ids e.g #nxtbtn and #prebtn.

Answer (score 2):

You have to do:

- validate if the code works correctly

Code:

```
var historyLinks = [];
var indexLink = 0;

$('#content').load("pages/sample.html", function(){
    //Load Content Using Menu Links
    $('.main-menu a').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        addLink(page);
        loadPage(page);
    });
});

$("#previousButton").click(function() {
    previous();
});

$("#nextButton").click(function() {
    next();
});

function loadPage(page) {
    $('#content').load('pages/' + page + '.html');
}

function addLink(page) {
    historyLinks.push(page);
    indexLink = historyLinks.length - 1;
}

function canGoPrevious() {
    return indexLink >=1;
}

function previous() {
    if(!canGoPrevious()) {
        alert('you can not load previous page');
        return;
    }
    indexLink = indexLink - 1;
    loadPage(historyLinks[indexLink]);
}


function canGoNext() {
    return indexLink + 1 < historyLinks.length;
}

function next() {
    if(!canGoNext()) {
        alert('you can not load next page');
        return;
    }
    indexLink = indexLink + 1;
    loadPage(historyLinks[indexLink]);
}
```

Comment: you could dry up your answer by using your `loadPage` function initially and using event delegation for the click handlers.

Comment: Hi thanks for the code, I want to add separate buttons then menu. Can you please let me know where to add these two ids lilke #nxtbtn and #prebtn.

Comment: @user2111911 has been added a code for you (previous/next button). If you are sure, that my code is useful, set my answer is correct.

Comment: @Seth ye, i know. if you wish - make changes in code :)

Comment: @W92 if you know then why don't you :D

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code but every time i click on next button its says you can load next page,  and on previous button that you can't load previous page, can you please let me know how where it is wrong, I want to enable or disable feature just point out the code. Thanks

Comment: Also i noticed the the menu links are not working i have to add return false to make it work, But it breaks the next previous button functionality

Comment: @user2111911 now your task is to validate code or repair it..now you have good background for developing the code